# How to make legend in R?

Tags: r, legend

I have data that falls into one of many categories.  Here is a very simplified version of what I'm doing to my data. I want to make a scatterplot where different colors represent different categories.  However, there are many different categories so instead of manually choosing the colors, I'm letting R choose for me by setting `col=data$category` within the `plot` function. However, I can't figure out how to generate a legend -- every parameter that I put inside the `legend` function never actually generates anything. Can someone help?

```
data <- data.frame(rnorm(50),sample(1:10,50,replace=TRUE))
colnames(data) <- c("data", "category")
plot(data$data, col=data$category)
legend("topright", data$category)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
legend("topright", legend=unique(data$category), pch=1, col=unique(data$category))
```

Comment: hmm it does produce a legend, but then when I spot-checked the colors that it displayed in the legend, they weren't displaying the right colors. Does it work for you?