# R: generate legend from dataframe variables

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a legend in R with reference to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688428/how-to-make-legend-in-r).

I have the following MWE, which more or less represents what I'm working with. dataframes a,b and c are generated over the course of a R script, with the colours. (there might be more, as the groups are generated by a loop)

```
a <- density(rnorm(100,mean = 5, sd = 1))
b <- density(rnorm(100,mean = 10, sd = 1))
c <- density(rnorm(100,mean = 7, sd = 1))
plot(c,col = "#FFCC00FF")
lines(b, col = "#FF6600FF")
lines(a, col = "#FF0000FF")
legendDataFrame <- data.frame(Group = c("A","B","C"), Colour = c("#FF0000FF","#FF6600FF", "#FFCC00FF"))
legend("topleft",legend=unique(legendDataFrame$Group), pch=1, col=unique(legendDataFrame$Colour))
print(legendDataFrame)
```

but, i get the image like this, with incorrect colours.. suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explicitly listing the colors, you can also try this if you want to maintain the dynamic functions:

```
legend("topleft",
    legend=unique(legendDataFrame$Group),
    pch=1,
    col=as.vector(unique(legendDataFrame$Colour)))
```

It adds `as.vector` to convert the factor (`unique(legendDataFrame$Colour)`) into a vector.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
legendDataFrame <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, Group = c("A","B","C"), Colour = c("#FF0000FF","#FF6600FF", "#FFCC00FF"))
```

P.S.
I smashed my head on `data.frame(stringsAsFactors=TRUE)` at least 1000 times. And I'm in good company:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/stringsAsFactors-FALSE-td921891.html 
http://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/ 
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html